# Report Builder 3.0 filter sharepoint list columns with the OR condition

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services

Report Builder 3.0 with Sharepoint List as data source, I want to use the same parameter (Value 1) to filter two columns if either Column 1 or Column 2=Value 1. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your two columns are in table,Then select the table and right click then you can see tablix properties.

Then Select Filter Tab and follow these steps:

1. In Expression Tab Select your Report Parameter
2. In Condition Box,Select the Required Condition
3. Choose the Columns with Or Condition then Save And try to Execute If not Click on Add button in Filter tab where you can put one more condition then save and execute.

Comment: Hi Kiran Kumar Talikoti,

Comment: Thanks for your help. It did not work. I found the answer from this link  https://denglishbi.wordpress.com/2011/01/28/reporting-services-ssrs-or-filter-logic/      Adding expression =Fields!ColA.Value=Parameters!Preference.Value OrElse Fields!ColB.Value=Parameters!Preference.Value with a Boolean type operator= true worked. Thanks a lot.